# Pyspark Dataframe copying the previous highest value(int or date) in the column

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Pyspark Dataframe with the following values in the amount column:
[input dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oHTLI.png)

The previous highest value has to be copied to the following records(rows) until a higher value was encountered in the column and so on.

The expected values in amount column is:
[output dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VloQD.png)

Can someone please help me in this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What you need is a window function using `MAX`, essentially a running max. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53415607/return-running-max-column-from-another-column-sql

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't clear, but seems to me you'd like to find the max "so far" for every row, until current row. In `SQL` it's going as follows -

First I'd add a simple `row_number` clause to the data. You'd have to have your `df` saved as a table, like this `df.registerTempTable('df_spark')` -

```
spark.sql(""" 
    SELECT 
        amount, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY RAND()) AS RN
    FROM df_spark
""").show()
```

Output -

```
+------+---+
|amount| RN|
+------+---+
|  2000|  1|
|  1000|  2|
|  1000|  3|
|  3000|  4|
+------+---+
```

Then, add the rolling `MAX` clause -

```
spark.sql("""  
SELECT 
    amount, MAX(amount) OVER(ORDER BY RN) AS rolling_max
FROM (
    SELECT 
        amount, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY RAND()) AS RN
    FROM 
    df_spark
)
""").show()
```

Output -

```
+------+-----------+
|amount|rolling_max|
+------+-----------+
|  1000|       1000|
|  3000|       3000|
|  1000|       3000|
|  2000|       3000|
+------+-----------+
```